# Adding Reference to Class LIbrary in Azure Function project causes assembly not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I dont really have much to go on here, but I have an Azure Function project (.NET Core 3.1 with Azure Functions v3)

This function has a Http Trigger which works perfectly on its own

However, as soon as I reference one of my existing projects, I get the error

```
    System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: MyFunction. 
FunctionApp2: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, 
Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Is this related to assembly binding?  How can I force this version to be available to my function application?

I dont have a web.config so the standard assembly binding wont work

Below is the file

[image]

I have tried adding the assembly directly to the project and that makes no difference

The project I am referencing doesnt have this package either so I am not sure which package this comes from

My function app has the following packages

```
<ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Fody" Version="6.5.1">
         <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
         <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
       </PackageReference>
       <PackageReference Include="LoadAssembliesOnStartup.Fody" Version="4.5.0">
         <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
         <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
       </PackageReference>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.3.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I tried to use Fody to ensure that the referenced project assembly is loaded on startup but that made no difference

As soon as I remove my other project it works fine

Paul

Comment: Is existing project also in .Net core 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem eventually, there is an issue with Redis and Azure Functions

I had to downgrade Redis and it worked