# Cannot add existing .NET Core 3.1 Project to Azure Function Project

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

When I add an existing .NET Core 3.1 project to my Azure Function I get

```
'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

The system cannot find the file specified."

When I try to execute a standard Http Trigger which works fine when the project is not referenced

This is a really frustrating issue that I have no idea how to resolve

How can I fix this or at least get information about what is causing it?

There is clearly some kind of compatibility issue but I have no idea where to start as the project reference I am trying to add has a lot of code in it

Are there any specific actions I need to take when preparing the function project like copying files, etc?

As soon as I reference my Class library, either directly or indirectly, I get this issue

I raised this question earlier

[Adding Reference to Class LIbrary in Azure Function project causes assembly not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086215/adding-reference-to-class-library-in-azure-function-project-causes-assembly-not)

I have raised this as a separate one as I think there may be specific actions I have to perform when referencing projects like this which may not be specific to my exact assembly

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Do you need to run the runtime version : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1?force_isolation=true

Comment: This doesnt seem to be an installer?

Comment: That is why there are two columns : Build Apps and Run Apps.

Comment: ah whoops! Will try the installer lol

Comment: No that didnt work

Comment: Im really struggling on this and it doesnt help that I cant see how to fix this with Assembly Redirects as its an Azure Function project

Comment: Install or not to Install.  That is the question.  Read the notes on the right side of the link.  There are bugs with Core 3.1 that still haven't been fix with assemblies.  Core was developed for people who wanted to use Net on LINUX servers and people who wanted to use Net on Mobile Devices.   So what should be included in the basic Core Library and what should be add-ins?  I don't think anybody really knows the answer.  Mobile users want to keep library small, Linus Server do not care if libraries get large.  One size does not fit all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234081/discussion-between-paul-and-jdweng).